# Fix on SOAP Client only -Content type mismatch

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, .net-core

I am using a third party Soap service. I have absolutely no access to server-side setting or code. I am getting the following error - 
"The content type text/html; charset=UTF-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 812 bytes of the response were: '

As I don't have access to server-side settings or code, I tried to fix it on client-side. I tried changing the binding from basicHttpBinding to wsHttpBinding. But it did not work. It is a siple http service with no credentials.

I expect to be able to fix it on the client-side.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you don’t know the service configuration on the server-side, we usually consume the web service by using the service metadata, which is often the below form.

> https://vabqia969vm/Service1.svc?wsdl

Then we create a console application, call the service by adding service reference.
[image]
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/accessing-services-using-a-wcf-client
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/how-to-add-update-or-remove-a-wcf-data-service-reference?view=vs-2019
Besides, please pay attention to the auto-generated configuration in the `Appconfig` file.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.